# Inner join en php

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo el siguiente código en PHP para poder llamar a una tabla desde MySQL

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM lugar WHERE Nombre NOT LIKE '' ORDER By id_lugar LIMIT 25";

if (isset($_POST['consulta'])) {
    $q = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['consulta']);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM lugar WHERE id_lugar LIKE '%$q%' OR Nombre LIKE '%$q%' OR ciuda LIKE '%$q%' OR region '$q' ";
}
```

El código, muestra la tabla ordenada como se encuentra en MySQL.

La tabla la tengo enlazada con primary y forean key a otra, pero quisiera insertar una columna a través de inner join, probando en phpmyadmin, funciona el metodo, pero no en el código php.

Tabla 1 - lugar

id_lugar

Nombre

ciudad

region

Tabla 2 - lugar_poblacion

id

id_lugar

id_poblacion

Tabla 3 - poblacion

id_poblacion

num_personas

num_casas

Quiero tomar la columna "num_personas" y añadirla a la tabla "lugar" a través de INNER JOIN

Comment: No se entiende la pregunta, ¿esto te funciona o regresa algun error?

Comment: Funciona, pero quiero agregarle el "INNER JOIN", donde y como debiese ir en esa funcion?

Comment: Falta que agregues aqui en tu pregunta la estructura de las tablas, de otro modo es difícil responderte

Comment: Si, mis disuclpas por eso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes resolverlo con esta consulta más o menos:

```
SELECT 
    l.Nombre,
    l.ciudad,
    p.num_personas
FROM lugar_poblacion lp
    INNER JOIN lugar l     ON lp.id_lugar = l.id_lugar
    INNER JOIN poblacion p ON lp.id_poblacion = p.id_poblacion
WHERE 
    l.id_lugar LIKE '%$q%' OR 
    l.Nombre LIKE '%$q%' OR 
    l.ciudad LIKE '%$q%' OR 
    l.region LIKE '%$q%'
```

Para mejor comprensión, puedes empezar los `JOIN` por la tabla que hace de enlace entre `lugar` y `poblacion` y seguir a partir de ahí.

Si observas, he usado alias cortos para cada tabla, luego, esos mismos alias hay que usarlos para referirse a cada columna, sea en los `JOIN`, sea en el `SELECT`, sea en el `WHERE` o en cualquier otra parte de la consulta.

Si hay alguna duda, dilo en comentarios.

### EDIT: para aclarar lo dicho en comentarios

El objetivo de los `JOIN` es unir todas las tablas en un sólo conjunto de resultados.

Si necesitaras incorporar los criterios que aparecen en tu primera consulta, sólo tendrías que hacer esto:

```
SELECT 
    l.Nombre,
    l.ciudad,
    p.num_personas
FROM lugar_poblacion lp
    INNER JOIN lugar l     ON lp.id_lugar = l.id_lugar
    INNER JOIN poblacion p ON lp.id_poblacion = p.id_poblacion
WHERE 
    l.id_lugar LIKE '%$q%' OR 
    l.Nombre LIKE '%$q%' OR 
    l.ciudad LIKE '%$q%' OR 
    l.region LIKE '%$q%' AND
    l.Nombre NOT LIKE ''
ORDER By l.id_lugar LIMIT 25
```

Hemos agregado a la consulta el criterio `Nombre NOT LIKE ''` como `AND` no como `OR` porque sería complementario a los otros, y hemos agregado el `ORDER BY`

Comment: Solo una duda, como tengo el codigo en php, dentro del segundo query, es donde debiese usar la consulta? sino, como hago para referirme a las otras tablas?

Comment: @Vikingo22 no necesitarías dos consultas, si las tablas se relacionan entre sí una de las grandes ventajas es precisamente hacer una sola consulta donde apliques todos los filtros o condiciones que requieras. A esta misma consulta le puedes añadir los criterios `WHERE` que necesites, si necesitas limitarla también le puedes agregar `LIMIT`, etc. Es una consulta como cualquier otra.

Comment: Pero entonces debiese llamar primero a la tabla que enlaza a las otras dos "Lugar_poblacion", y luego en el segundo query, usar el INNER JOIN?

Comment: @Vikingo22 no. En la explicación del código he dicho precisamente lo siguiente: *Para mejor comprensión, puedes empezar los JOIN por la tabla que hace de enlace entre lugar y poblacion y seguir a partir de ahí.* Si analizas la consulta SQL, ya estás implicando a esa tabla (es la primera que se usa) en los `JOIN`, no necesitas meterla de nuevo por ningún otro lado. Las consultas con `JOIN` lo que hacen es poner en relación los registros de diferentes tablas y mostrarlos en un resultado. En tu planteamiento hay un error de comprensión: los `JOIN` no meten datos de unas tablas en otras ...

Comment: ... lo que hacen es unir información, pero la información permanece en sus tablas respectivas. Lo que tú haces con los `JOIN` es presentar datos agrupados u ordenados de acuerdo a los criterios indicados en esa consulta.

Comment: Por eso, pero me refiero a que en el primero query que utilizo, debo llamar a la tabla en comun, para luego en el segundo query, usar las columnas que necesito de las tablas que estan anexadas? o puedo seguir usando el primer query con cualquiera de las dos tablas, y luego en el segundo, con JOIN, llamar las columnas de la otra tabla?

Comment: No, no necesitas dos querys para esto. En una sola consulta pones todos los criterios que hagan falta, ese es precisamente uno de los objetivos de las tablas relacionales. Imagina que tienes millones de registros, sería una locura llamar primero a todos esos registros para luego de ellos sacar los que te interesan. Esos millones de registros están en sus tablas y en la consulta tú pones los filtros necesarios para traer **sólo** los datos que te interesan. Por tanto el `WHERE Nombre NOT LIKE ''` y el `ORDER By id_lugar LIMIT 25` de la 1ª consulta lo puedes expresar en una única query.

Comment: Me queda muchisimo mas claro. Millon de gracias!! por el tiempo y la paciencia.

Comment: @Vikingo22 de nada. Ahora edito la respuesta indicando cómo agregar los criterios adicionales, de modo que te quede una sola consulta.